# Table layout alignment within a horizontalscrollview & scroll view in android

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <RelativeLayout 
         android:orientation="horizontal" 
         android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
         style="@style/TitleBar">

    <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                  android:textColor="#ffffff" 
                  android:id="@+id/createpatientheader" 
                  android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                  android:text="New Patient Registration" 
                  android:maxLines="1" 
                  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
                  android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:background="#81BEF7"
   android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
      android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
   >  
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

       <TableLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@+id/patient_fields"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:background="#81BEF7"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:stretchColumns="*">

           <TableRow>

               <TextView
                   style="@style/TextViewStandard"
                   android:gravity="left"
                   android:text="Name *"
                   android:textColor="#ffffff" 
                   android:layout_weight="1"/>

               <EditText
                   style="@style/EditTextStandard"
                   android:id="@+id/patientname"
                   android:hint="At least 3 Alphabets"
                   android:layout_span="2"
                   android:singleLine="true"
                   android:maxLength="30"
                   android:inputType="textPersonName"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow >
           <TextView
                   style="@style/TextViewStandard"
                   android:gravity="left"
                   android:text="Date of Birth"
                   android:textColor="#ffffff"
                   android:layout_weight="1" />

               <EditText
                   style="@style/EditTextStandard"
                   android:id="@+id/dob"
                   android:layout_span="2"
                   android:singleLine="true"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   />
               <DatePicker android:id="@+id/dateofbirth" 
                           android:visibility="gone"/>"
           </TableRow>

           <TableRow>
               <TextView
                   style="@style/TextViewStandard"
                   android:gravity="left"
                   android:padding="3dip"
                   android:text="Mobile"
                   android:textColor="#ffffff" 
                   android:layout_weight="1"/>
               <EditText
                   style="@style/EditTextStandard"
                   android:id="@+id/mobile"
                   android:layout_span="2" 
                   android:singleLine="true"
                   android:numeric="integer"
                   android:maxLength="10"
                   android:layout_weight="1"/>
           </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want both scroll bar in my application.I have tried with this code. If I place all controls inside the scroll view, then all the controls are streched and it filled the screen. But if i put it inside the horizontal scroll, it is not streched and not filled in the screen. I am missing something in that.. help me..